# Make an element in an <li> tag inline unless the contents of the <li> don't all fit in one line

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a list that looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>swans:</span> none
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>ducks:</span> none
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>geese:</span> lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
  </li>
</ul>
```

By making it so that the span is display:block, I can make it look like:

```
swans:
none

ducks:
none

geese:
lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
```

What I want is to make it so that the span is not display:block if the contents of the li tag all fit into one line, so, assuming there's not enough horizontal space for the 3rd item it would look like:

```
swans: none
    
ducks: none
    
geese:
lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
```

I assume there's a way to do this with flexbox but I can't seem to figure it out. What am I missing?

Comment: Just `display: inline-block`?

Comment: "I assume there's a way to do this with flexbox ... What am I missing?" `flex-wrap:wrap;`

Comment: oh wait, I don't think there's a solution for this without putting the *remainder* of the text in a second `<span>`

Comment: That's OK I can change the HTML, let me try it out. I put nowrap on the second div, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 22px;
}
li span {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

ul {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>swans:</span> none
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>ducks:</span> none
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>geese:</span> lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
  </li>
</ul>
```